# Transformation matrices, true/false statement

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got a question regarding transformation matrices, following statement:

Let $f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ be orthogonal projection on the line $l:t(1,1,1), t \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $A$ be its transformations matrix. Then rank(A) is less than nulldimension(A), for which the examiner says its true.

I don't really understand how i'm supposed to find out the answer. This is a question where we will only answer true/false, which means you should be able to draw your conclusions from theory, which I'm not able to do.

Thanks!

Comment: The projection is onto. A line is $1$ dimensional. So the rank (the dimension of the image) is $1$. By the Rank-Nullity Theorem, since the domain is dimension $3$, the rank plus the nullity must add up to $3$. So the nullity (the dimension of the nullspace of $A$) must be two. So the claim that the rank is strictly smaller than the nullity is true.

Comment: The nullspace will be orthogonal to the column space. Since the orthogonal compliment of a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a plane it is two dimensional. Since the column space determines he rank it is one dimensional. Therefore the rank is less than the dimensional of the nullspace.

Comment: So you mean that regardless of what dimension we are in, the rank will always be one for orthogonal projection? both $f:\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ and $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ has rank 1?